# How to get scrollbar value in two label in different form

Tags: c#

I create an application that can display the temperature (in label) with a hscrollbar in 2 different form. I have 2 form, one is call "Capteur" and she have a label and the scrollbar, the second is call "Afficheur" and who have a label as well. 
In the form "Capteur" I change the text label easily with the event ValueChanged :

```
        private void HReglageTemperature_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            afficheur.Temp = this.hReglageTemperature.Value;
            this.lTempCapteur.Text = string.Format("{0}°C", afficheur.Temp); //lTempCapteur is the name of the label
        }
```

but in my form "Afficheur" (which is the form2) I can't change the text of my label by the value of the scrollbar, since I don't have ValueChanged event of the scrollbar.

I only have this code in my form "Afficheur":

```
    public partial class Afficheur : Form {

        int temp = 0;

        public Afficheur() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public int Temp {
            get => temp;
            set => temp = value;
        }
```

I have already tried to add in my ValueChanged event the name of the label of the form "Afficheur" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Using ValueChanged in the second form doesn't make sense because it doesn't have a scrollbar.  Hard to guess what you want, but consider to make the Temp property setter smarter, also let it update the label's Text property.

Comment: Yes, for the ValueChanged in the second form, in thinking back it's stupid.

I would like that when I move the bar of the scrollbar, it updates the label of the form "Capteur" and that of the form "Afficheur", in real time.

Comment: Then I guessed correctly.